# Firefox PDF preview option not working ubunutu 14.04?

Tags: firefox, pdf

I started to use Firefox recently, and I have a constant problem. Every time I want to open a PDF link I want to preview it in a tab instead of saving the file. I changed the parameter for the actions on PREFERENCES > APPLICATIONS 
[The parameter for PDFs is on Preview in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1gnJ.png)

I set in that way, but after a couple of days it always returns to the "save file option"

Any idea of what could be happening?

Comment: Argh, I remember this happening to me! I can't seem to remember how I fixed it! :(

Answer (score 0):

[should have commented but didn't as I couldn't comment yet.]

Well that's odd, I wonder there's a third party program protecting or changing your preferences, or some addon doing the same. Check if there's anything as such.